# Simple question concerning the argument "breaks" of hist()

Tags: r, data-visualization, histogram

When I run

```
> hist(precip, breaks = 10)
```

I get the following histogram:

[image]

According to the document, `breaks` is "a single number giving **the number of cells** for the histogram" in this case. However, as you can see, there are 13 bars(one of them has zero height) on the outputted plot, while `breaks` is specified as `10`. Why?

Comment: Hint: the software chose nice intervals (of length 5).  To do that, it had to make a compromise.

Comment: Got it. Nice intervals(35, 20, 10, 5, 2, etc) are chosen automatically to keep the plot pretty.

Comment: The help you referred to answers your question. The second-last sentence under the section on `breaks` says "* In the last three cases the number is a suggestion only; the breakpoints will be set to ‘pretty’ values.*" -- yours is one of those three cases. If you want an exact number of breaks you can always specify the set of breakpoints.